# How can I connect my dumbphone to my laptop so I can transfer data?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, 3g

I want to provide a makeshift 3G networking connection for my laptop, because I don't have WiFi or Ethernet at home, but I do have 3G Internet access through my phone. My phone is an AT&T Alcatel Go Phone, and it has a small USB port which is used for the power adapter. I need some way to hook it up to my Macbook to transfer files from my phone. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What about bluetooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3G networking uses the cellular network to connect. You do not have access to the same 3G network with your laptop unless you have purchased a 3G card for it. Therefore, you can not establish a wireless network between your phone and laptop using 3G.

To transfer files from your phone to your laptop, you will need to get a data transfer cable. Many of the charging cables that come with phones now, are also data cables. If your charging cable has a USB end that plugs into the charger, you may be able to use it to connect to your laptop. The ends will look like this (*USB-A to USB-micro*);

[image]